# Matlab Function Representation

Tags: matlab

I understand that if I wanted to generate y values of y=sin(2x) I could do:

```
y = sin(0:.01:2*2);
```

However, if I wanted to generate values for where y = 0 unless x is a multiple of 1 or sqrt(2) at which points y=1, how would I approach that problem? Must I create a window around the values and hope the step size is small enough to capture it? Thank you.

Comment: I can't find any correlation between the various specific points you're naming.  sqrt(2) as an input to sin?  However, in general, you can never rely on floating point numbers to give you an exact equality, so if you're trying to solve that equation for y=0 or whatever, don't do it this way.  Finally, your syntax does not do sin(2x).  Operator precedence makes it instead do sin(0:0.01:4).  Generate x first and plug that in.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. I am used the sin(2x) as an example of how I understand how to generate values given some function, but if the function is not well represented, how could I generate the values. Such as the function for f(x) = 1 if x = n(sqrt(2)) for n in N and x = 0 elsewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logical conditions. For example,starting from some `y(x)` then `y(y==1)` will generate y's value for this condition and zeros elsewhere. For more generic conditions you can use `mod` and `ismember` etc. Another issue you'll have is to match integers to floats, you'll have to round first and then use the functions mentioned above.

Comment: The problem here is that the data I generate for y is dependent upon my input x. Could I use a two dimensional vector for the conditions? Say I have some '[X,Y(x)]' then use a conditional statement to generate the y values that meet the condition and leave the others alone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it.  Again, floating point arithmetic doesn't do equality, so your example won't work.  Also, since you're sampling the function at discreet intervals, it's hard to capture delta functions.  So don't do it this way.  If, instead, you're looking for standard piecewise functions, here's the idea:

```
x = 0:.01:2;
x1_locations = x < 1;
x2_locations = ~x;
y = zeros(size(x));
y(x1_locations) = sin(2*x(x1_locations));
y(x2_locations) = cos(3*x(x2_locations));
```

Once more, the reason this won't work for, say, `x1_locations = (floor(x/sqrt(2)) == x/sqrt(2))` is that you're never going to hit the exact location of x that will show this, and even if you did, roundoff error in the floating point representation may still make you miss the location.  If you're okay with approximation, use a maximum absolute difference from the values you're interested in.

Comment: I understand that I am sampling the interval over discrete intervals so I couldn't possibly use equality, but what I am trying to do is essentially represent  a periodic Kronecker Delta function. But I think that using the maximum absolute difference (giving me a small window) with conditionals will do this for me.